# Android Custom Checkbox selector issue

Tags: android, layout, checkbox

I have to customize a checkbox to show 2 different state while checked, i am using the following 2 images :

[image]

[image]

My custom selector is defined as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/favourite_normal" android:state_checked="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/favourite_choose" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/favourite_normal"/>
```

But thing is i am not getting proper result as in the image does not fills my checkbox view properly if i change the height and width of the checkbox which i have to do to adjust. The result i am getting like this:

[image]

The complete layout is given below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="74dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_bav_btn">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/jokeListViewBackButton"
                    android:src="@drawable/back_screen_button_normal"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="37dp"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="Large Text"
                        android:id="@+id/jokeTitleTextView"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                        android:textColor="@color/fontWhiteColor" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="37dp"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="0/0"
                        android:id="@+id/jokeCountTxt"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                        android:textColor="@color/fontWhiteColor" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

                <CheckBox
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
                    android:button="@drawable/custom_favourite_selector"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:checked="false" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:background="@color/listViewBody"
        android:layout_weight="0.71">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView" >

            <com.gravityapps.framework.Utils.CustomTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text=""
                android:id="@+id/jokeTextView"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/navbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bottom_nav_back"
            android:id="@+id/prevButtonLayout"
            android:clickable="true">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:background="@drawable/previous_btn_normal"
                android:layout_margin="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bottom_nav_back"
            android:id="@+id/randPrevButtonLayout"
            android:clickable="true" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:background="@drawable/reverse_btn_normal"
                android:layout_margin="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bottom_nav_back"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
            android:clickable="true" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:background="@drawable/copy_btn_normal"
                android:layout_margin="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bottom_nav_back"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
            android:clickable="true" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                android:background="@drawable/share_btn_normal"
                android:layout_margin="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bottom_nav_back"
            android:id="@+id/randNextButtonLayout"
            android:clickable="true" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:background="@drawable/forward_btn_normal"
                android:layout_margin="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bottom_nav_back"
            android:id="@+id/nextButtonLayout">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:background="@drawable/next_btn_normal"
                android:layout_margin="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I am not sure why i am getting this result. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why **that horrible layout nesting**? One layout per single View???? You should know that nesting layouts **has a negative effect on performances**.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i do optimization and refinements on view at the final phase of the development actually, not sure whether its a right things to do or not.

Comment: what is resolution of your images??

Comment: its 67x67 sized image

Comment: You might want to have a look into https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/icons.html#icons-system-icons

Comment: Or check the icon sizes of your emulators. Mine are found at: `[your drive letter]:\[your IDE path]\sdk\platforms\android-xy\data\res` under the various `drawable` folders

Answer (score 2):

The size of `Checkbox` 40dp*40dp smaller than the image you defined in selector.

use `wrap_content` instead of static dimensions.

Comment: But that makes my checkbox much bigger which does not look good, what shall do to resize the checkbox then? change the image size, if thats the case then is there no other way to employ without image size change?

Comment: @aaa111 try to set `android:button="@null"` and add `android:background="@drawable/custom_favourite_selector"` , if this not working i think you should resize your image to support different screen sizes

Comment: Weird this seems to be working.Is this a valid way to do?

Comment: @AhmedM.Abed Your comment saved my day man!! :D Setting button to null and changing background to the drawable selector works.

Comment: @CantThinkOfAnything happy to know that bro, Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the previous answer, if you don't want your checkbox to be larger, than you will have to resize your images. I think these are your best options, either you *wrap_content* your checkbox width and height or you resize your image resources into smaller, ex. 40*40px